# Is it possible to identify what the parent program/app is from a running process?

Tags: terminal, bash, memory, cpu, macos

I'm able to find processes using `top` or `ps`. That's no problem.

Sometimes I find that some processes are taking up a lot of memory or cpu and I'm trying to identify what the root program is.

For instance, the process `sort` sometimes just ends up taking 2-3 gigs of memory over like 4 hours. I'd like to know what program initiated the `sort` process so I can try and fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ps` has an option to access the `PPID`/parent PID of a process:

```
$ ps aux -o ppid
USER               PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND           PPID
admin            65694  10.9  0.1  4385132  13340   ??  UN    9:32PM   0:00.07 /System/Library/     1
```

`PPID` is the last column in this case.

(Or use Activity Monitor by selecting `View` -> `All Processes, Hierarchically`)

Comment: Are you sure this is a right command? I have an error:
`$ ps -aux -o PPID`
`ps: No user named 'x'`
`ps: PPID: keyword not found`
`ps: no valid keywords; valid keywords:`

Comment: I‘m not close to a Mac righting, might have gotten that wrong

Comment: @user3439894 It works now:) But the problem is, that I don't see the process name in `COMMAND` tab, just the start of the path (16 chars)

Comment: @Mateusz Szlosek, Try using `ps auxc -o ppid` instead, you will at least get the executable name of the process to show right before the `ppid`.  Also read the manual page for `ps`.

Comment: `ps -ef` will show PID and PPID in the second and third columns.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [htop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98253/how-do-i-install-htop-inside-mac-os-x) and show "tree" precesses (by pressing `F5`) there. Here's an example:

[image: htop example screen]

Comment: I ended up using `htop` for my needs (before seeing this answer) and it worked great. Thanks! I chose the other Answer because it was what I was originally looking for and it didn't require extra binaries to perform.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS users, in accordance to [@nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside) answer, please use:

```
ps auxo ppid
```

This will simply add the `ppid` column to the **default "u"** columns.

flags explanation:

- **a** (other users process)
- **u** (columns: *user, pid, %cpu, %mem, vsz, rss, tt, state, start, time, and command*)
- **x** (also non terminal processes)
- **o** (specify keywords for extra columns)