# Activity Monitor: Is there a way to sum up child processes into their parents?

Tags: cpu, activity-monitor, sort

I really like the Hierarchical view in activity monitor for finding which process belongs to which application. The problem is that when you sort by "% CPU" it sorts by the value of the parent, not including the sum of its child processes. Is there a way to get it to include the child processes?

So for example, the screenshot below shows that "Smart Converter" is running on 5.4% of the CPU, but its child process "ffmpeg" is running on 1213.1% of the CPU. What I'm looking for is it to show 1218.5% for "Smart Converter", which is 5.4 + 1213.1. That way when you sort, it shows you the applications that are using the most CPU, then in turn, which child processes are using the most.

[image: Activity Monitor Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Does it have to be Activity Monitor or are you open to show the info in [Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302060/is-it-possible-to-identify-what-the-parent-program-app-is-from-a-running-process)?

Comment: Also, if you're trying to see power hungry apps, you can always go into the Energy tab. High CPU usage should correlate enough.

Comment: @fsb Thanks! I'm not opposed to using terminal, activity monitor was just my first choice since this is it's main purpose.

Comment: @X_841 You're right, the energy tab mostly correlates with the CPU use. But the same issue appears on the Memory/Disk/Network tabs though. When viewing the hierarchy, it doesn't include the child processes.

Comment: Windows' Task Manager is much better. It shows sum of related processes.