# Knowing which program runs a process at macos startup

Tags: macos

I would like to know if it is possible to know which program launches which process?

In my current case, I have the impression that my "nginx" is not controlled by "brew", because when I retrieve the list of brew services I have:

[image]

and when I run

`brew services stop nginx`

nginx is still running in the activity monitor.

[image]

Comment: Is it the same as https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/302060/74657 ?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely started by [launchd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd).  But you can see it’s Parent Process ID (PPID) with `ps -ef` and follow the PID/PPID back.